# How to trigger animation only after a sequence of animations have completed dynamically

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm a complete beginner. I'm trying to create code that can handle animating any number of elements depending on information from an xml file. There are four steps I'm trying to accomplish.

1. Fade in all child elements of a container div, one by one until all elements are visible.
2. Delay, and then fade out all elements in the container div at once.
3. Move on to the next container div and do the same with the child elements there...and so on.
4. Loop.

So far, I'm still stuck on step 1. I can get the child elements to fade in sequentially, but they all fade in, regardless of which container div they belong to. And then everything disappears. Until I can get the first container div to fade in all elements and then disappear without triggering anything else, I can't move on to figuring out the rest. I've tried a ton of different things but I can't quite get there and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code so far:

```
$('.element').find('.inner').each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(2000*index).fadeIn(2000); 
});
$('.inner').promise().done(function() {
// my callback
    $('.element').delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For timing issues and synchronizing animations in jQuery there is a cool plugin: [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/). It provides *very easy chaining syntax*. The following example code is a single chain:

```
// 1. Fade in all child elements of a container div, one by one until all elements are visible.
// 2. Delay, and then fade out all elements in the container div at once.
$('.someDiv .inner').each($).fadeIn(2000,$).all().wait(4000).fadeOut(2000);
```

To loop that behaviour for multiple divs you also need the repeat() method from that plugin. Again we have a single jQuery chain that does all the waiting for all animations automatically:

```
// Move on to the next container div and do the same with the child elements there...and so on.
// Loop.
$('.divs').repeat().each($).find('.inner')
    .each($).fadeIn(2000,$).all().wait(4000).fadeOut(2000,$);
```

This is the whole code for your animation.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

For step 1:
You should fadeIn the first child of the div and in the complete callback function passed to fadeIn get the next sibling of the element and fade it in until there are no more next siblings.  Something like this (pseudo code):

```
var fadeInCallback = function(evt) {
  //this will reference the object that fadeIn was called on
  if( $(this).next().size() > 0 ) {
    $(this).next().fadeIn( 2000, fadeInCallback );
  }
};
$('.element div:first-child').fadeIn( 2000, fadeInCallback );
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: You probably want to use the 'first' selector rather than 'first-child': http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/